# How to use amp-bind for amp pages

Tags: javascript, amp-html

I am trying to put my page in amp.

For that I need pagination which I'm trying to implement like this,

```
<amp-list [src]="'https://api.mydomain.com/id/?page=' + pageNumber">
<button on="tap:setState(pageNumber: pageNumber+1)" >next page</button>
```

Here the page number increases as I go on clicking.
To use on="tap:setState" I need to include amp-bind.js and I did it like in the script below:

```
<script async custom-element="amp-bind" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-bind-0.1.js"></script>
```

When I run the code I got the error as

```
v0.js:68 Experiment "amp-bind" is disabled.
```

When I try enabling it through this

```
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfGCAjUU4pDu84Sclw6wjGVDiFJhVr61pYTMehIt6ex4wmr1Q/viewform
```

I am not sure how to do it for local.

Can you help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can enable [experiments](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/tree/master/tools/experiments) locally via the console:

```
AMP.toggleExperiment('amp-bind')
```